# bash completion of makefile target

Tags: makefile, bash-completion

Suppose I have a simple makefile like:

```
hello:
   echo "hello world"

bye:
   echo "bye bye"
```

Then in bash I want something like:

> make h < tab >

so it can complete to

> make hello

I found a simple way like creating empty files `hello` and `bye` but I'm looking for something more *sophisticated*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> #### This answer from 2010 is outdated - the project mentioned here seems to have been discontinued.

Could this be what you're looking for?

http://freshmeat.net/projects/bashcompletion/

> make [Tab] would complete on all
> targets in Makefile. This project was
> conceived to produce programmable
> completion routines for the most
> common Linux/UNIX commands, reducing
> the amount of typing sysadmins and
> programmers need to do on a daily
> basis.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: @JonasStein thanks, I'm going to delete this one since I didn't find an alternative link for this projects. There's a lot of newer answers than mine

Comment: Oops I cannot delete because it's accepted. I'll leave a note.

Comment: try this. https://github.com/scop/bash-completion

Answer (score 90):

Add this in your **~/.bash_profile** file or **~/.bashrc** file

```
complete -W "\`grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+:([^=]|$)' ?akefile | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$//'\`" make
```

This searches for a target in your Makefile titled 'Makefile' or 'makefile' (note the capital `?` wildcard in `?akefile`) using grep, and pipes it over to the `complete` command in bash which is used to specify how arguments are autocompleted. The `-W` flag denotes that the input to the `complete` command will be a wordlist which is accomplished by passing the results of grep through `sed` which arranges it into the desirable *wordlist* format.

Caveats and gotchas:

1. Your make file is named 'GNUMakefile' or anything else other than 'Makefile' or 'makefile'. If you frequently encounter such titles consider changing the regular expression `?akefile` accordingly.
2. Forgetting to source your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc file after making the changes. I add this seemingly trivial detail since, to the uninitiated it is unfamiliar.
   For any change to your bash files to take effect, *source* them using the command

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

   or

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```

PS. You also now have the added ability to display the *possible* make targets by pressing [Tab] twice just like in bash completion. Just make sure you add a space after the command make before typing [Tab] twice.

Comment: I personally use: `complete -W "\`make -qp | sed -n -E 's/^([^.#\s][^:=]*)(:$|:\s+.*$)/\1/p' | sort -u'\`" make`

Comment: I think it would be good to handle the case of no Makefile in cwd:
complete -W "\`([[ -r Makefile ]] && grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+:([^=]|$)' Makefile || cat /dev/null) | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$//'\`" make

Comment: your solution is not detecting command that contain a point "."

Comment: @ahmedbhs Updated to include recognition of "."

Comment: they should not consider .PHONY and .env etcc so this is my suggestion
complete -W "\`grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+:([^=]|$)' Makefile | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$//'\`" make

Comment: I need to install bash-completion in order to run this on my centos
`sudo yum install bash-completion`

Answer (score 15):

There's a useful package called [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) available for most every OS. It includes Makefile completion.

(If you're using macOS and [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), you can get this via `brew install bash-completion`.)

Comment: for macOS - there is bash-completion@2 which directly conflicts with bash-completion. Encouraged to use @2 version if your bash >= 4.1. It doesnt seem to have Makefile completion included so adding custom rule in bashrc as raised in other answers might help.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be default in at least Debian Lenny:

```
$ grep Makefile /etc/bash_completion
    # make reads `GNUmakefile', then `makefile', then `Makefile'
    elif [ -f ${makef_dir}/Makefile ]; then
        makef=${makef_dir}/Makefile
    # before we scan for targets, see if a Makefile name was
    # deal with included Makefiles
```

The header of this file states:

```
#   The latest version of this software can be obtained here:
#
#   http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/
#
#   RELEASE: 20080617.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a completion script that looks at the .PHONY: declaration.

```
_make_phony_words() {
  local opt_revert

  if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION:-}" ]; then
    shopt -q nullglob || {
      opt_revert=1 ; shopt -s nullglob ;
    }

  elif [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ]; then
    [[ -o nullglob ]] || {
      opt_revert=1 ; setopt nullglob
    }
  fi

  for f in ./?akefile ./*.make ; do
    sed -nEe '/^.PHONY/ { s/^.PHONY:[ ]?// ; p ; } ' "$f" | tr ' ' $'\n' | sort -u
  done

  if [ -n "$opt_revert" ]; then

    [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] && unsetopt nullglob
    [ -n "${BASH_VERSION:-}" ] && shopt -u nullglob
  fi
  unset opt_revert

}

_make_phony_complete() {
  local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

  COMPREPLY+=( $(compgen -W "$( _make_phony_words )" -- ${cur}) )

}
complete -F _make_phony_complete make
```

Answer (score 2):

### Makefile completion on steroids!

I had **2 problems** with the normal completions:

#### Problem #1

Sometimes you have targets you want to call like `make greet:hi` and `make greet:hola` sort of like namespacing `Makefile` target names. So your `Makefile` ends up looking like:

```sh
greet\:hola:
   echo "hola world"

# OR a .PHONY target
.PHONY: greet\:hi
greet\:hi:
   echo "hi world"
```

In this case the auto-completions after `:` don't show up as it uses `\:` in the Makefile as shown above.

#### Problem #2

There wasn't a way to navigate through the list of all `Makefile` targets that match my input using arrow keys (or `CTRL-p` / `CTRL-n`) in my `bash` shell.

Basically, I wanted to use fuzzy search like approach on the targets (i.e. `fzf`).
FZF Repo: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

### Solution

##### Install FZF Dependency

###### Using Homebrew

You can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (on macOS or Linux)
to install fzf.

```sh
brew install fzf
$(brew --prefix)/opt/fzf/install
```

###### Using Linux package managers

| Package Manager | Linux Distribution | Command |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APK | Alpine Linux | `sudo apk add fzf` |
| APT | Debian 9+/Ubuntu 19.10+ | `sudo apt-get install fzf` |
| Conda |  | `conda install -c conda-forge fzf` |
| DNF | Fedora | `sudo dnf install fzf` |
| Nix | NixOS, etc. | `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.fzf` |
| Pacman | Arch Linux | `sudo pacman -S fzf` |
| pkg | FreeBSD | `pkg install fzf` |
| pkgin | NetBSD | `pkgin install fzf` |
| pkg_add | OpenBSD | `pkg_add fzf` |
| XBPS | Void Linux | `sudo xbps-install -S fzf` |
| Zypper | openSUSE | `sudo zypper install fzf` |

#### FZF and `:` compatible auto-complete command

Put this in your `.bashrc`

```
complete -W "\`grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[\\:]*[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+:([^=]|$)' ?akefile | sort | uniq | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$//' | sed 's/[\]//g' | fzf\`" make
```

Now just typing `make`  and then hitting the  key will work!

### DEMO: in action!

Then you can use as following:

[make using `fzf`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gejbT.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I added so I follow "include" directives in Makefile. So my .bashrc looks like this:

```
function followMakefile() {
  grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+:([^=]|$)' ?akefile | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$//'
  for x in `grep -E '^include' ?akefile | sed 's/include //'`
  do
    grep -oE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+:([^=]|$)' $x | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$//'
  done
}
complete -W "\`followMakefile\`" make
```

Answer (score -3):

In Ubuntu 10.04, source the following file:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

or uncomment it in

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```